# How to timestamp a bash command

Tags: bash, command, alias

I am pretty new to bash scripting. I am trying to do a small project where I timestamp a bash command/alias. I am trying to timestamp when I update home brew. So before I run **brew update**, I would like to see when I ran the command last.

Comment: See `HISTTIMEFORMAT` in the man page.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T " && history | grep "brew update"`, then it will print the date and time on the left of all the brew update commands.

Comment: Thank you, however when I try to make an alias for that command it doesn't print it

Comment: `alias brewtime='HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T " && history | grep "brew update"'` should work. Maybe you could comment down your alias command.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
echo "Last Update: "
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T " && history | grep "brew update"

Comment: I saved the file as BrewLastUpD

Comment: It seems as though making a script wouldn't work, because there is no way to echo the output of the commands, but making an alias command works. Here's what you need to type into the shell to make the alias command: `alias BrewLastUpD='echo -n "Last Update: " && HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T " && history | grep "brew update | tail"'`. I added the tail command to only see the last line(the latest command). There's no need to make a script. If you want to make this alias permanent, then you need to add that line to your `.bash_profile` file in the home directory.

Comment: If the `.bash_profile` file doesn't exist in your home directory, then you can still make a new one.

Comment: Make sure you don't forget the `.` in the beginning of the file name.